# Is there any apply family member that can do this in R?

Tags: r, plot, arguments, apply

I'd like to create this function:

```
densidad<-function(x){
  Epa(x,xis[1])+Epa(x,xis[2])+
  Epa(x,xis[3])+Epa(x,xis[4])+
  Epa(x,xis[5])
}
```

But I wonder if there's a way to don't write all the sums and instead use an apply family member. This function comes from this code:

```
# Creemos una función que nos arroje un Kernel de Epanechnikov:
Epa<-function(x,xi,h=0.8){
  y <- ifelse(xi-h < x & x < xi+h,
              (3/4)*(1-((x-xi)/h)^2)*(1/h),
              0)
  return(y)
}

# Queremos utilizarla para muchas xi's
aux<-function(xi,Add,Col){
  curve(Epa(x,xi=xi),
        from=-5,to=5,
        lwd=2,
        add = Add,col=Col)
}
aux(0,F,"darkblue")

# Usemos una entidad apply nueva. El objetivo será aplicar
# la función anterior a estos puntos:
xis=c(0,0.5,-2.5,1,2)
# Con estos parámetros respectivamente:
Adds=c(F,T,T,T,T)
Cols=rainbow(5)

mapply(aux, # Aplica esta función
       # Con los siguientes parámetros para la
       xis,  # primera entrada.
       Adds, # segunda entrada.
       Cols) # tercera entrada.


densidad<-function(x){
  Epa(x,xis[1])+Epa(x,xis[2])+
  Epa(x,xis[3])+Epa(x,xis[4])+
  Epa(x,xis[5])
}

curve(densidad(x),from=-5,to=5,lwd=2)
mapply(aux, # Aplica esta función
       # Con los siguientes parámetros para la
       xis,  # primera entrada.
       rep(T,5), # segunda entrada.
       Cols) # tercera entrada.
```

What can I do then?

Comment: How about `sum(sapply(1:5, function(i) Epa(x, xis[i])))`?

Comment: What is `Epa()`?

Comment: @dcarlson I was thinking perhaps `rowSums( sapply(1:5, function(i) Epa(x, xls[i] ) ) )` It might depend on whether `Epa` was vectorized. and in this case it appears to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use lapply to store each value in a list and then unlist them and sum the result.

```
output <- sum(unlist(lapply(list(xis), function(i) Epa(x, i)))
```

Or your could rewrite your densidad function to accept a vector or list.

```
densidad <- function(x, xis){
  y <- 0
  for (n in xis){
      y <- y + Epa(x, n)
  }
  return(y)
}
```